# Generating combinations of a string in a list [Python3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string `"dog"` and I wan't to generate all possible combinations with letters from that word.

Output would be something like this:

```
["dog","dgo","ogd","odg","god","gdo"]
```

Order does not matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools

word = 'dog'
result = [''.join(new_word) for new_word in itertools.permutations(word)]

print(result)
```